# How to match a pattern which is NOT inside a string/comment?

Tags: php, regex

Environment: PHP 5.3

I'm trying to write my own query parameter substitution method. Basically I want to take this:

```
select * from xxx where a=? and b>?
```

and convert it to

```
select * from xxx where a=1 and b>2
```

Naturally, assuming that values for all the `?` parameters are known. OK, so that's a bit simplified, but enough for the question.

So, what I need to do, is to find all the `?` marks in the given string. Easy, right? But there's one catch: I don't want to find the marks that are inside strings or comments. So, in this string:

```
select *  -- I know * is bad, but just once can't hurt, right?
from xxx /* ? */ where a=? and b='Question?'
```

Only one of the `?` marks should be replaced.

My intuition tells me that PHP's `preg_replace()` *should* be up to the task... but my regex knowledge fails me in constructing an appropriate pattern. :( I could also just parse it "by hand", but I'm worried that the performance will take an inappropriate hit.

So - can this be done quickly via regexes (and if yes, what would be the pattern), or should I just parse it manually character-by-character?

Comment: Is this just for fun or does this have a reason? Why need a personal parametrize framework?

Comment: What kind of SQL dialect is that?

Comment: you made it even harder to do since you allow comments inside your queries

Comment: @Nanne - this does have a reason. I'm trying to make an simple, lightweight interface for doing MySQL queries, built on top of the native MySQLi.

Comment: @MelvinProtacio - I just want it to be as fool-proof as possible.

Comment: @vilx : I suppose you know about PDO, I don't think that's too heavy, but you apparently do?

Comment: @Vilx- If you're doing this on top of mysqli, then doesn't prepare/bind_param already do this?

Comment: @derobert - Yes, but that's where those "extra features" come in that I intended to make. MySQLi's parameter binding has a syntax so ugly I've rarely seen worse. Come on, passing an extra string with the parameter types? And on top of that - if you simply pass it a query, you cannot determine (wihtout using half-documented hacks) whether the query produced resultsets or not. At least the standard `MySQLi::query()` returns a `MySQLi_result` or TRUE, depending on what the query was.

Comment: @derobert - So I intend to make a syntax with two advantages: first, parameter types are embedded in the markers. So in truth it won't be `?` that you write, it will be `?s` or `?i` and the like. Another also, a few additions, like `?x` that will put the string in there unescaped, etc. Finally, parameter reuse. The syntax `?1s` would mean to use the first parameter, so you can specify the parameter once, and then refer to it multiple times in the query.

Comment: @Nanne - ok, sorry about that previous comment. PDO is available after all. Though I read in the PHP manual that it's unable to use all of MySQL's features (which MySQLi does). No idea what those features are, but...

Comment: @Vilx-: You may just want to borrow Oracle's syntax then. `SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = :param AND taz = :param`, uses `param` for both. Another advantage is that PDO takes that syntax, too (so it'll be familiar to a lot of PHP folks)

Comment: @derober - I'll think about it. Maybe. Or maybe I will move to PDO after all, I don't know. I just can't seem to make up my mind about the whole thing. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult problem for regexes. A parser would be more suitable, but as long as certain constraints are met, regexes might just work. The constraints are:

- no nested comments
- no escaped quotes inside strings
- no single quotes inside comments
- no comment delimiters inside strings
- all quotes and comments are correctly balanced
- there is a maximum line length that you can specify

If those are the case, then you can simply look for a `?` that is

- not preceded (on the same line) by `--`.
- not followed by `*/` unless `/*` occurs first and
- followed by an even number of quotes,

Assuming a maximum line length of 100, this gives you

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%(?<!--.{0,100})    # Assert no -- preceding on this line
    \?                   # Match a ?
    (?!                  # Assert that it\'s impossible to match...
     (?s:                #  (allowing the dot to match newlines here):
      (?!/\*)            #  (and making sure there is no intervening /*)
      .                  #  any character
     )*                  # zero or more times, if that string is followed by
     \*/                 # */
    )                    # End of lookahead
    (?=                  # Assert that it *is* possible to match
     (?:                 # the following regex:
      [^\']*\'[^\']*\'   #  a string containing exactly two quotes
     )*                  #  repeated zero or more times
     [^\']*              # followed by only non-quote characters
     $                   # until the end of the string.
    )                    # End of lookahead.
    %x', 
    'REPLACE', $subject);
```

Comment: Ouch! That's a long list of requirements! In truth, the reason for all this is that I want it to accept anything thrown at it, and make as much sense of it as possible. Your list of requirements just makes everything worse. I guess then that a regex is not the right tool for the job this time!

Answer (score 1):

You may try first removing all question marks in comments and remember them and put a placeholder in the query, then parse your query via preg_replace() and then insert question marks in comments back where there are placeholders.
I mean sth like

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\/\*.*?.*\*\//U', $query, $matches);
preg_replace('/\/\*.*?.*\*\//U', $arrayWithIndicesOfParameters, $query);
preg_replace(/*your replacement of parameters*/);
preg_replace($arrayWithIndicesOfParameters, $matches, $query); //str_replace should be sufficient here
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone else may have a more elegant solution, but my first instinct is to use regex to strip the comments entirely, and then pattern match parameters.

```
$expressions = array(
  "#/\*(.*)\*/#",
  "#[-]{2}(.*)\\n#",
);
$query = preg_replace($expressions, "", $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this:

- Find a regular expression for each the string syntax and the comment syntax.
- Combine them to match either string syntax, comment syntax, or ‘anything else’.
- Perform the replacement on each ‘anything else’ part.

Here’s an example implementation:

```
$escapeSequence = "(?:\\\\[0'\"bnrtZ\\\\%_])";
$singleQuoted   = "'(?:[^'\\\\]|{$escapeSequence}|'')*'";
$doubleQuoted   = "\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|{$escapeSequence}|\"\")*\"";
$string         = "(?:{$singleQuoted}|{$doubleQuoted})";

$lineEndComment   = "(?:#[^\\r\\n]*|--\\s[^\\r\\n]*)";
$multiLineComment = "(?:\/\\*(?:.|[\\r\\n])*?\\*\/)";
$comment          = "(?:{$lineEndComment}|{$multiLineComment})";

$pattern = "/({$string}|{$comment})/";

$parts = preg_split($pattern, $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
for ($i=0, $n=count($parts)-1; $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    $part = $parts[$i]; // non-string, non-comment part
    // perform replacement of ?
}
$query = implode('', $parts);
```

The pattern might not be complete but it should be enough to get the idea.